# PhoneStateListener is not working properly in Nougat

Tags: android, audio-recording, video-recording, phone-state-listener

Here I'm Calling PhoneStateChangeListener class in onCreate method.

the code is:

```
PhoneStateChangeListener pscl = new PhoneStateChangeListener(MainActivity.this,true);
                            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                            tm.listen(pscl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

PhoneStateChangeListener class is:

```
class PhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {


Context context;
Boolean doRecording=false;

public PhoneStateChangeListener(Context context,Boolean doRecording) {
    this.context = context;
    this.doRecording=doRecording;
}
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    Log.d("CallRecorder", "PhoneListener::onCallStateChanged state:" + state + " incomingNumber:" + incomingNumber);
    //Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, RecordService.class);
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_IDLE, stoping recording");
            Boolean stopped = context.stopService(new Intent(context, RecordService.class));
            Log.e("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_IDLE starting recording---------------------------------"+isMyServiceRunning((getClass())));
            Log.i("CallRecorder", "stopService for RecordService returned " + stopped);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.d("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
            doRecording=false;
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            if(doRecording) {

                Log.d("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK starting recording");
                Log.e("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK starting recording---------------------------------" + isMyServiceRunning((getClass())));
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, RecordService.class);
                ComponentName name = context.startService(callIntent);
                if (null == name) {
                    Log.e("CallRecorder", "startService for RecordService returned null ComponentName");
                } else {
                    Log.i("CallRecorder", "startService returned " + name.flattenToString());
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

The phonestatechangelistener is working well below nougat, **Issue is when a call starts it calls CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK and the service gets started but when the call is ended it doesn't call CALL_STATE_IDLE and thus service is not stopped** this problem is there above marshmallow.

Comment: Facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Just deactivate your `PhoneStateListener` when your call ends:

```
private void deactivatePhoneStateListener(){
    if(mPhoneStateListener != null){
        mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
    mPhoneStateListener = null;
}
```

Activate it again whenever you need it:

```
private void activatePhoneStateListener(Context context){
    mPhoneStateListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Comment: as in the question it is mentioned, we are not getting  CALL_STATE_IDLE so how can we deactivate?